# How can I create widget with timer?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-widget

I am working on one application with has a widget functionality So I have designed a widget but tried with timer.

widget is working on background after kill the app.so can you guide me to set current time on my widget.

Answer (score 1):

You can use timer as chronometer. it work like countdown timer and you don't need background service for that.

**You Can Implement like this :**

> Widget XML

```
           <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chronometer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="6dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

> AppWidgetProvider

```
val view = RemoteViews(context?.packageName, R.layout.timer_widget)
val startTime: Long = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
view.setChronometer(R.id.chronometer,startTime+120000,"%tH:%tM:%tS",true)
view.setChronometerCountDown(R.id.chronometer,true)//if you want to reverse countdown
appWidgetManager?.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view)
```